# How to filter &nbsp; in textarea with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

btw: i know that using regex is not the best idea in the world...

For example i have such input variants:

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
```

or

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
```

or

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

and i want to check my input like: all except `<p>` with `&nbsp;` in every amount of them (0, 1 or 50)...

i wrote such expression:

```
/[^<p>(\s*&nbsp;\s*)*<\/p>]/ig
```

and seems that it works, **but!**

for example i have such input:

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;t&nbsp;</p>
```

or

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;tttt&nbsp;tttt</p>
```

and it is thinking, that it is equal to my regex...

not a good idea...

what i do wrong in my regex?
or maybe there are some better ways of solving this?

Comment: what's your expected output? Your regex is totally wrong.

Comment: @RoyiNamir what do you mean by all?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think he wants to eliminate p's with merly nbsps inside

Comment: @AvinashRaj i need to only test! to validate
no replace!

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, you are not right. Read above...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 what do you want, match or replace?

Comment: @AvinashRaj match...

 
i use it as pattern for angularjs input...

and whant to create validation-check

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming** you want to eliminate all `<P>'s` with only `nbsp;` (or more) inside them : then :

Assuming you have this

```
var a='a<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>c<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>d<p>&nbsp;aa &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>e';
```

And assuming the yellow part has to go : becuase it contains `aa` inside :

You'll be left with all except the problematic P with pure nbsps :

[image]

Then this code :

```
a=a.replace(/(<p>.*?<\/p>)/g, function(match, p1 ) {
  if (/^<p>(\s*&nbsp;\s*)*<\/p>$/ig.test(p1)) 
  return '';
  else return p1;
})
```

Will yield :

```
acd<p>&nbsp;aa &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>e
```

As you can see - the `P` tag wasn't removed because of `aa`

http://jsbin.com/cizidayeru/3/edit

Comment: i use it as pattern for angularjs input... so replace seems that is not for my case...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 look how much information you omitted from your question : angular , no need replace ...etc . Your question is very vague

Comment: as for me all is pretty clear.
i din't wrote about replace anything

Comment: Rob also understood replace - so i guess your q wasnt very clear. Nevermind . Wait for other answers

Comment: a little bit edited your code:
`$scope.checkContentOnWhiteSpaces = function() {
        var contentWithoutWhiteSpaces = '';
        if (typeof $scope.article.Text!== 'undefined' && $scope.news.Content !== ''){
          contentWithoutWhiteSpaces = $scope.news.Content.replace(/(<p>.*?<\/p>)/g, function(match, p1 ) {
            if (/^<p>(\s*&nbsp;\s*)*<\/p>$/ig.test(p1)) 
            return '';
            else return p1;
          });
        }
        if (contentWithoutWhiteSpaces === ''){
          $scope.eventForm.content.$setValidity('valid', false);
        }
      };`

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is pretty close, you want:

```
.replace(/<p>(\s*&nbsp;\s*)+<\/p>/ig,'<p>&nbsp;</p>');
```

That will match `<p>` followed by one or more occurrences of `\s*&nbsp;\s*` followed by `</p>` and replace them with `<p>&nbsp;</p>`.

Or did you want only single `&nbsp;` to remain the multiples to be removed entirely? In that case, you'll want:

```
.replace(/<p>\s*&nbsp;\s*(\s*&nbsp;\s*)+<\/p>/ig,'')
```

Noting that you shouldn't use a regular expression for processing HTML. ;-)

#### Edit

If you only need to test for it, then use:

```
/<p>(\s*&nbsp;\s*)+<\/p>/.test(string);
```

for one or more and:

```
/<p>\s*&nbsp;\s*(\s*&nbsp;\s*)+<\/p>/.test(string);
```

for two or more.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse HTML in DOM before rendering it to the page.  This provides some benefit, since you won't have to include the tagname in the Regex.  The additional benefit is that your paragraph elements may include other attributes, like class names, data-* information, or inline-styling; which would all fail your Regex test.

Because this is being parsed into the DOM before being added to the body, there is a third benefit in that you don't have to look for `&nbsp;` in your Regex, you can simply look for spaces `\s` (or inversely any non-whitespace characters).

### jQuery

```
var strText ='a<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>c<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>d<p>&nbsp;aa &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>e',
    $div    = $('<div/>').html(strText),
    $p      = $div.find('p');

var empty_paragraph_count = 0;
$p.each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  if ( /^\s*$/.test( $this.text() ) ){
    empty_paragraph_count++;
    // uncomment this line if you want to remove the paragraph:
    // $this.remove();
  }
});
```

Then you are free to do whatever you want with the `$div.html();` and `empty_paragraph_count` will reveal how many paragraphs were empty or only had spaces.

---

### Vanilla

If you're looking for a VanillaJS solution, you can use the same approach:

```
var strText       = 'a<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>c<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>d<p>&nbsp;aa &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>e',
    div           = document.createElement('div'),
    div.innerHTML = strText,
    p             = div.getElementsByTagName('p');

var empty_paragraph_count = 0;
for(var i=0, n=p.length; i<n; i++){
  if( /^\s*$/.test( p[i].textContent ) ){
    empty_paragraph_count++;
  }
}
```